Discrepancy between grouped and ungrouped output of HSD.test from agricolae package in r
HSD.test with group=TRUE assigned different significance letters to all three groups in the PlantGrowth dataset, but when HSD.test is run again with group=FALSE, the control group shows no significant difference from the other treatments. Why would this occur, and does this mean the letter groupings from HSD.test don't always indicate significant differences between groups?
My code is here
Anova<-aov(PlantGrowth$weight~PlantGrowth$group)
summary.aov(Anova)
HSD.1<-HSD.test(Anova, "PlantGrowth$group", alpha = .95, group=TRUE)
HSD.1
HSD.2<-HSD.test(Anova, "PlantGrowth$group", alpha = .95, group=FALSE)
HSD.2

Results from the grouped test
> HSD.1<-HSD.test(Anova, "PlantGrowth$group", alpha = .95, group=TRUE)
> HSD.1
$statistics
    MSerror Df  Mean       CV       MSD
  0.3885959 27 5.073 12.28809 0.0851231

$parameters
   test            name.t ntr StudentizedRange alpha
  Tukey PlantGrowth$group   3        0.4318156  0.95

$means
     PlantGrowth$weight       std  r        se  Min  Max    Q25   Q50    Q75
ctrl              5.032 0.5830914 10 0.1971284 4.17 6.11 4.5500 5.155 5.2925
trt1              4.661 0.7936757 10 0.1971284 3.59 6.03 4.2075 4.550 4.8700
trt2              5.526 0.4425733 10 0.1971284 4.92 6.31 5.2675 5.435 5.7350

$comparison
NULL

$groups
     PlantGrowth$weight groups
trt2              5.526      a
ctrl              5.032      b
trt1              4.661      c

attr(,"class")
[1] "group"

Results from ungrouped test
> HSD.2<-HSD.test(Anova, "PlantGrowth$group", alpha = .95, group=FALSE)
> HSD.2
$statistics
    MSerror Df  Mean       CV       MSD
  0.3885959 27 5.073 12.28809 0.0851231

$parameters
   test            name.t ntr StudentizedRange alpha
  Tukey PlantGrowth$group   3        0.4318156  0.95

$means
     PlantGrowth$weight       std  r        se  Min  Max    Q25   Q50    Q75
ctrl              5.032 0.5830914 10 0.1971284 4.17 6.11 4.5500 5.155 5.2925
trt1              4.661 0.7936757 10 0.1971284 3.59 6.03 4.2075 4.550 4.8700
trt2              5.526 0.4425733 10 0.1971284 4.92 6.31 5.2675 5.435 5.7350

$comparison
            difference pvalue signif.        LCL        UCL
ctrl - trt1      0.371 0.3909          0.2858769  0.4561231
ctrl - trt2     -0.494 0.1980         -0.5791231 -0.4088769
trt1 - trt2     -0.865 0.0120       * -0.9501231 -0.7798769

$groups
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "group"

I would expect, based on the grouped test, for trt1 and trt2 to be significantly different from the ctrl group, but the ungrouped test shows that only trt1 and trt2 are significantly different.

You probably want alpha = 0.05, not 0.95.
Let me also simplify your code a bit:
Anova <- aov(weight~group, data=PlantGrowth)

HSD.1 <- HSD.test(Anova, "group", alpha = .05, group=TRUE)
HSD.2 <- HSD.test(Anova, "group", alpha = .05, group=FALSE)

Which gives:
HSD.1$groups
     weight groups
trt2  5.526      a
ctrl  5.032     ab
trt1  4.661      b

So, the control group is not significantly different to any of the treatments, while treatment 1 is significantly different to treatment 2 (at the 0.05 level of significance), and this is consistent with the ungrouped method:
HSD.2$comparison
            difference pvalue signif.        LCL        UCL
ctrl - trt1      0.371 0.3909         -0.3202161  1.0622161
ctrl - trt2     -0.494 0.1980         -1.1852161  0.1972161
trt1 - trt2     -0.865 0.0120       * -1.5562161 -0.1737839

Specifying a 0.95 level of significance is unheard of in this day and age.
